# Clangd shows false errors when compilation works just fine

Tags: clang, clangd

I usd clangd as my language server for C in Neovim. I recently cloned a few C source code repositories (Suckless's [DWM](https://git.suckless.org/dwm/) and [Neovim](https://github.com/neovim/neovim)) and wanted to take a look at the source code. Clangd gave me errors that did not occur during compilation.

I did not modify the source files in any way, shape or form. I don't know how to describe some of these errors other than by giving examples.

Including some header files resulted in errors. In `dwm.c`, for X11 header files (`#include <X11/Xft/Xft.h>`), I got a "In included file: 'ft2build.h file not found" error (but the file exists). Same in `neovim/src/nvim/main.c` with `#include nvim/arglist.h`.

I have errors like "Expected ')'" in `dwm.c` in

```
updatestatus(void)
{
    if (!gettextprop(root, XA_WM_NAME, stext, sizeof(stext)))
        strcpy(stext, "dwm-"VERSION); // Error is on this line
    drawbar(selmon);
}
```

For Neovim, some of these include: "Unknown type name 'Loop'" in [neovim/src/main.c (permalink)](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/0774d0cfe1d5efb4bdd34cc8cf3799af5c947d2e/src/nvim/main.c) on line 122:
`Loop main_loop;`
and "Initializer element is not a compile-time constant on line 127:
`static const char *err_arg_missing = N_("Argument missing after");`.

Obviously, one would expect these to fail to compile, but they compile without any kind of error and work (I've run both of them after compiling). How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://clangd.llvm.org/installation#project-setup?

Comment: That solved it. Thank you!